# Tray Menu Slides Down After Content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking at this menu, but am having a weird issue I can't seem to figure out--and feeling kind of stupid over! I want it to slide down as a tray menu over existing content. However, it slides down underneath the content. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Help?

https://jsfiddle.net/ticklishoctopus/gdfv4wzn/

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
      $('ul.sub-menu').each(function() {
        var width = 0;
        $(this).children('li').each(function() {
          width += $(this).width();
          console.log('inner width' + $(this).width());
        });
        console.log('total width' + width);
        $(this).css('padding-left', $(window).width() / 2 - width / 2);
      });
    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin);
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Cabin, sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      background-color: #ade;
    }

    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

    ul,
    li {
      list-style: none;
      text-indent: none;
    }

    .menu {
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 50;
      display: block;
      background: blue;
      height: 110px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-image: url('images/gradient-line.png');
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-position: left bottom;
      padding-right: 30px;
    }

    .menu .menu-item {}

    .menu .menu-item a {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      font-size: 13pt;
      line-height: 64px;
      height: 100px;
      font-weight: 700;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 5px 30px;
      margin-top: 25px;
    }

    .menu .menu-item .sub-menu {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: -50px;
      z-index: -1;
      transition: all .5s;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .menu .menu-item .sub-menu li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .menu .menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
      top: 150px;
    }

    .menu .menu-item .sub-menu .menu-item a {
      text-align: center;
      background: rgba(155, 75, 105, .8);
      padding: 0 20px;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      color: #ddd;
      border: none;
      height: 64px;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    .menu .menu-item .sub-menu .menu-item a:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .menu .menu-item:hover .sub-menu .menu-item a {
      height: 64px;
      display: block;
      opacity: 1;
      filter: alpha(opacity=100);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    .sub-menu {
      background-color: #fff;
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

      <header>

        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">MENU 1 <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">History</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">News &amp; Conventions</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Customer Service</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">MENU 2 <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Catalog</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sketches</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">MENU 3 <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Catalog</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sketches</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </header>

      <p class="clear"></p>

      <main>

        Content goes here.

      </main>

    </body>
```

Comment: Set a z-index on the child elements so that they are higher than the parent. It looks like you only set z-index on the parent. The children will inherit that z-index unless you implicitly set the children z-indexes.

Comment: Changing those settings doesn't seem to game a difference. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Upon further review of your script - it appears that your menu is not "position:fixed", but your submenu is. z-index is relative to its parent ONLY if the parent is position:fixed. Basically, when you choose position "fixed" you take the element out of the normal DOM flow and as a result, z-index has no meaning outside of the parent/child relationship.

Comment: So how might this affect the menu appearing under the content? It appears with the menu itself just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, you have to have positioned elements all the way down to the sub-menu.   It also helps to wrap the menu ul itself in a positioned div with a higher z-index than the page content:

```
.header-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
.menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    background: blue;
    height: 110px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('images/gradient-line.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left bottom;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.menu .menu-item {
  position: relative;
}
.menu .menu-item a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13pt;
    line-height: 64px;
    height: 100px;
    font-weight:700;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thanks for the help.